# Cant add cookies with request to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, fetch

I am using React at the frontend (i am new to react) and for the backend I am using express.js and for authentication using express-session (actually tried jwt to but setting token at the server like res.cookie() it didnt work to).
So what my want is when user logged in correctly server sets a cookie and then if u want to get your user data give your user data by checking your session id. I write my backend code and try it from POSTMAN and it worked. but when i am trying to do this at react it didnt worked. I tried so much things using axios, using fetch request. When react post for login at the client in response headers it shows me Set Cookie and my cookie:
[image: Set-Cookie, Response Headers]
If i know correctly it sets the cookie and we can see it at the request headers but my request headers dont have that:
[image: Request Headers]

And my application > cookies page is empty to.
But when user logged in correctly it is doing the job correctly and show us the username but when we redirected him and want to get user data it is setting the cookie to default:
[image: Empty cookie]
Client code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
    })
    const loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { username, password } = data
        try {

            fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({username, password}),
              })
              .then(json => json.json())
              .then(response => console.log(response))


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }
```

So what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing the *credentials: 'same-origin'* in fetch request. You need to use fetch request like this for including the cookies in header

```
fetch(loginUrl, {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
})
```

This may help you. Please let me know if issue resolved or not. It will be better if you share your code how you are using fetch for making request.

Comment: I didnt share my code because i tried lots of ways and none of them worked so i wanted a fresh try. When i tried your code it did same thing like last one. It is doing it for that request but it is not writing it to the cookies and dont save them for other calls.

Comment: node server
```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors({
  orign: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}))
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}))
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
  });
```

Comment: so by using my code are you still not able to see the cookie in request header? could you please provide react code?

Comment: I edit my main question for react code you can see it from there